# Auto hide bar for JavaFX

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm looking for auto hide bar for JavaFX. I saw previously that this is developed into component library for JavaFX but I cannot find it. Do know where I can find this bar?

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking of the HiddenSidesPane from the ControlsFX project.

http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/